# What is "+id+" used for?

Tags: javascript

What is this?:

```
document.getElementById("+id+")
```

I have seen this used several times in code on other sites, and I was wondering what it's specific use was and if there is an alternate to using this code.

**--- Edit ---**

[Here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/113377/HTML-JavaScript/Acessing-Function-Properties) is an example of one of the sites I recently saw it on.

Comment: It's very unlikely you saw this code in this exact form - it wouldn't work, as an ID must not contain `+` signs. Can you show a live example?

Comment: That's not `"+id+"`, it's `''+id+''`, most likely to make sure `id` is interpreted as a string.

Comment: @Anders just posted an answer pointing that out, no one seems to have noticed because the question has double quotes :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, everyone seems to have missed the fact that those are **2 single quotes and not a single double quote** :)

```
document.getElementById(''+id+''); //two single quotes
```

This is equivalent to the below except it seems to be doing string concatenation before the value is passed.

```
document.getElementById(id);
```